# Any way to show the TLS certificate with tcpdump?

Tags: tls

I'm troubleshooting a certificate issue and I'm looking to see what the proxy is sending to the client for its certificate. I added the tcpdump process to get this output, but I can't seem to figure that out.

Is there anyway to use some tooling to see the certificate? I mean the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` all the way to the end of the certificate.

I saw ssldump as well but doesn't look like it provides that information.

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark easily provides the certificate information when viewing the traffic as TLS, at least with TLS 1.2 and lower. With TLS 1.3 the certificate is encrypted and thus can not be determined when sniffing the traffic.

Note that the certificate is not transported in the traffic as PEM but as DER. This can be easily exported with Wireshark (export packet bytes of the certificate) and then converted to PEM, for example using `openssl -in cert.der -inform der -out cert.pem`.

If there is only tcpdump available for sniffing then one can use it to capture the traffic into a file and then later use Wireshark on another system to analyze the captured data.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just loaded the tcpdump into wireshark and looks like it is TLS 1.3, so sounds like there isn't a way with this route to get the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `openssl` to view the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname.domain.tld:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So this is in an mTLS communication between two processes. I tried that but unfortunately I got the response `Connection refused` from openssl. Wasn't sure if there was another way.